# Gaussian integral times polynomial

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm trying to calculate

$$
I = \int_0^\infty dq\ \frac{e^{-qm^2 - R^2/(4q)}}{q^{d/2}}, \quad R, m \geq 0,\ d \geq 1
\tag1$$

To do it, I apply the change of variables,

$$
q = \alpha^2, \quad dq = 2\alpha d\alpha
\tag2$$

This renders,

$$
I = \int_0^\infty d\alpha\ \alpha^{1 - d}e^{-\alpha^2m^2 - R^2/(4\alpha^2)}
\tag3$$

I tryied to solve it and  I looked for it in books and even Wolfram-Alpha, but I don't get any solutions. Any suggestions to solve Eq. (3)?

---

**EDITION**

Knowing the solution for $d = 0, d = 3$, would it be correct to use them and take derivatives respect to $R^2$ to generate the solutions to the rest $d$'s? For that pair of $d$-values, the solutions depend on $\sqrt{R^2} = R$, so would it be right to use

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial(R^2)} = \frac{\partial R}{\partial(R^2)}\frac{\partial}{\partial R} = \Big(\frac{\partial R^2}{\partial R}\Big)^{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial R} = \frac{1}{2R}\frac{\partial}{\partial R}
$$

or not? Probably it is a naive question, but I would like to have a second opinion. Actually, this is the same as integrating those results respect to $m^2$.

Comment: For $d=1$, use Glasser's  matter theorem. Then generalise by integrating $d-1$ times with respect to $m^2$.

Comment: Matter or Master? By Matter I don't find anything. Could you tell me about the theorem? And thanks for the comment

Comment: @J.G. What do you say about my edition to the post?

Comment: Sorry, master, yes. Your addition to the question is a valid idea.

Comment: I think you can use [Schwinger's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_parametrization).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known that the modified Bessel function of the second kind can be written in an integral form

$$ K_{\nu}(z) = \frac{z^{\nu}}{2^{\nu+1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t-z^{2}/4t}}{t^{\nu+1}}\,\mathrm{d}t. $$

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698509/modified-bessel-function-integral-representation-proof-k-nuz-fracz-nu) has some more information on its derivation. Identifying $\nu = d/2-1$ and $z = Rm$, one can write the integral as

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-m^{2}q-R^{2}/4q}}{q^{d/2}}\,\mathrm{d}q = 2\left(\frac{2m}{R}\right)^{d/2-1}K_{d/2-1}(Rm). $$

Comment: In **this** Bessel function, $\nu$ can be any number, either positive, negative, integer or non-integer, true?

Comment: Yes, however, there will always be a singularity at $x = 0$, so cases where $R = 0$ and $m = 0$ for your integral need to be handled separately. Both can be written in terms of the gamma function, with additional restrictions on $d$ because the gamma function has singularities at the non-positive integers.