# Inverse Laplace Transform for $ sK_0(\sqrt{as}) $?

Tags: laplace-transform, heat-equation, inverse-laplace

Are there any ways to manipulate the following in order to make it invertible from Laplace space analytically?

$$ sK_0(\sqrt{as})$$

where $a$ is a constant.

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of $s\cdot K_0(\sqrt{s})$. If so, Mathematica fails to find any closed form representations.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I think I was asking two questions at once in a very muddled way.  I simplified to just one through edits. Still getting the hang of this, thanks for the help.

Comment: Mathematica yields the following for me: `InverseLaplaceTransform[s*BesselK[0,Sqrt[a s]],s,x]` gives `(E^(-(a/(4 x))) (a - 4 x))/(8 x^3)`, or $e^{-a/(4x)}(a-4x)/(8x^3)$. (WolframAlpha is unfortunately not quite smart enough for this.)

Comment: @Semiclassical I think perhaps your computer is a bit more powerful than the $300 laptop I am currently typing on. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Laplace transform pair appears in Erdelyi's [bible](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/1/Volume%201.pdf) of integral transforms (eq. (30) on p.516) :

$$f(t)=\frac{1}{2t}\exp\left(-\frac{a}{4t}\right)\leftrightarrow F(s) = K_0(\sqrt{as})=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-s t}f(t)\,dt.$$

I write the explicit transform to recall that integration-by-parts implies

$$F(s)=-\left[\frac{1}{s}e^{-st}f(t)\right]_{0}^\infty+\frac{1}{s}\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f'(t)\,dt$$
The behavior as $t\to 0$ isn't as nice as one would like, but the exponential factor suppresses the $1/t$ divergence and so $f(0)=0$. Hence we have

$$s K_0(\sqrt{as})=s F(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-s t}f'(t)\,dt$$

and therefore the requisite inverse Laplace transform is $$f'(t)=\left(-\frac{1}{2t^2}+\frac{a}{8t^3}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{a}{4t}\right)=\frac{a-4t}{8t^3}\exp\left(-\frac{a}{4t}\right).$$

---

Here is a partial proof of the identity. (I regard it as a partial proof because I can't justify some of the formulas used.)

I begin with the integral representation

$$F(s)=K_0(\sqrt{as})=\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x^2+as}}\,dx.$$

According to Mathematica, one has $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+as}}\right]=\frac{e^{-tx^2/a}}{\sqrt{a \pi t}}$$ and therefore the inverse transform of $F(s)$ may be represented as $$f(t)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t x^2/a}}{\sqrt{a \pi t}}\cos x\,dx.$$

Leaving this up to Mathematica, we obtain $f(t) = (2t)^{-1} e^{-a/4t}$ as claimed.

Notes:

- (1) is not the standard form of this representation (compare equation [10.32.E6](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E6), but I've rescaled the integration variable to suit my purpose. For the derivation, the verification shown in the answer to this earlier [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698509/modified-bessel-function-integral-representation-proof-k-nuz-fracz-nu) may provide a lead.
- The functions in (2) are simple enough that one may perhaps verify the Laplace transform by hand and the inverse Laplace transform via the Bromwich integral.
- If I was being rigorous, I'd need to justify writing $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\mathcal{L}[g(x,t)](s)\,dx=\mathcal{L}\left[\int_0^\infty f(x) g(x,t)\,dt\right](s)$$
  ...but you'd better believe I can't be bothered.
- If we consider $\cos x$ as the real part of $e^{i x}$, then we may view (3) as the real part of a computable Gaussian integral. So this is tractable by hand. (We may also regard it as a Fourier cosine transform, and as such is almost certainly in Erdelyi's table as well.)

---

I couldn't resist one more try, and the result is worth it. We start from the integral representation

$$K_0(\sqrt{as})=\frac12 \int_0^\infty\exp\left(-x-\frac{as}{4x}\right)\frac{dx}{x}$$

(see eqn. 10.32.10 of the DLMF). We then make the substitution $t=a/(4x)$, obtaining

$$K_0(\sqrt{as})=\frac12 \int_0^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{a}{4t}-st \right)\frac{dt}{t}$$

which upon reflection is nothing other than the Laplace transform of $f(t)=\dfrac{1}{2t}\exp\left(-\dfrac{a}{4t}\right)$.

Comment: Note: I've tried for a bit to derive eq. (30) by my own power, and have thus far failed...

Comment: I can't claim to be able to derive eq.(30) either, but the identity and subsequent proof is found in Ragab (1962) eq.(5) and eq.(6).  It's been a big help for my work. https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/jlms/s1-37.1.391

Comment: Interesting. My abortive attempts were centered on the two integral representations $$K_0(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x^2+s^2}}\,dx=\frac12 \int_0^\infty\exp\left(-x-\frac{s^2}{4x}\right)\frac{dx}{x},$$ with the thought of computing the inverse-transform of the integrands and subsequently compute the integral. Looking at Ragab 1953 (which he cited in his 1961 paper) makes me think the second of those two may be be worth pursuing.

Comment: Better for me to have said I can't claim "to have derived" eq.(30) either. It's clear you're able. I'm still mucking about in the looking up other people's work stage. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Semiclassical Your third point in "Notes" can be justified using this well-know property for the Laplace transform (essentially, an application of the Fubini-Tonelli theorem):  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis

Comment: As a side note, my final and quickest attempt uses the same integral representation at Ragab 1953. So I think that's a good note to end on.

Comment: @Semiclassical, unfortunately I've found that the inverse transform you provided doesn't solve my ultimate problem. If this is allowed, I'll add on 2 more questions that you might be able to help me with?

Comment: If it doesn't change the spirit of the original problem, sure. Otherwise I'd suggest you create a new problem and link it to this one. @NA

Comment: Probably best to start a new problem. I put a link to this question in that one. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4024099/842334